# Resque: Does dequeueing kill the process?

Tags: resque

I'm implementing resque on this project where I need the feature of killing whatever gets enqueued to resque. So, I've seen that there is a dequeuing method, which will remove the jobs from the queue. But, if this job has already been started, and is currently running, does dequeuing kill the process?

Also important: If a job gets dequeued, do I get a handle where I can do something, or is an exception thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue was actually using one of the many extensions for the resque gem, called resque-status. This handles worker instances, assignes a unique id to each of them (which I can use to identify them, feature I needed the most) and provides me with a kill method to be called on a job, which will guarantee that the job will process the kill signal the next time I call a certain method of their API (not exactly a kill and assign exception, but it's better than nothing).

Answer (score 0):

As far I know it `don't kill` the `process` its just remove the job from the queue if it exist check [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque/job.rb#L181-197)

But if you want to achieve killing a job perhaps then you need to use various signal that resque provide

Here a list of them

```
Resque workers respond to a few different signals:

QUIT - Wait for child to finish processing then exit
TERM / INT - Immediately kill child then exit
USR1 - Immediately kill child but don't exit
USR2 - Don't start to process any new jobs
CONT - Start to process new jobs again after a USR2
```

In your case if would be `USR1`

Hope this help

Comment: That seems nice, but I need the forked pid for that. Where can I find it? is it stored in redis?

Comment: @ChuckE Ohh well there is no easy way because resque doesnot do it AFAIK I may be wrong as well though 1) `ps aux | grep [r]esque ` 2) Do `Process.pid ` inside your job code and store them in redis make sense

Comment: I'm not sure about that. resque forks many processes, which means at some given point I might have many processes, which will unexpectedly abort. Resque.dequeue allows me to remove some jobs of the queue by job class and arguments. I'd like to do the same with the processes. I guess this makes more sense when inside the library, if it's not already, i'll probably suggest the feature.

Comment: @ChuckE ohh you want find abort process well that you can find using resque